# SpringDataCouchbase - Not able to save map with collection as value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

Tried to save Person entity with below attributes in couch base, but not able to save getting error, **see below error log**.

**Note**: Issue in Spring boot 3.X onwards, Spring-data -couch 5.X onwards not facing in 4.X

I see call of method `getPropertyAccessor(val)` called from

```
private CouchbaseDocument writeMapInternal(final Map<? extends Object, Object> source, final CouchbaseDocument target, TypeInformation<?> type, CouchbasePersistentProperty prop)
```

is causing issue and and result of `getPropertyAccessor` is never used.

**How to resolve?**

Entity

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    private Map<String, Version> versions;
    @Field
    private Map<String,Map<String,String>> releaseVersions;

    public Person(){

    }
}
```

Error

```
2023-05-09 16:36:27 Unable to make field private transient java.util.HashMap java.util.HashSet.map accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @10656728 ERROR_MESSAGE=Unable to make field private transient java.util.HashMap java.util.HashSet.map accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @10656728
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.util.HashMap java.util.HashSet.map accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @10656728
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:787)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.CouchbaseMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(CouchbaseMappingContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.CouchbaseMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(CouchbaseMappingContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.CouchbaseMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(CouchbaseMappingContext.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getPropertyAccessor(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:986)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.writeMapInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:730)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.createMap(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:651)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:582)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:298)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.writeToTargetDocument(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:582)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.writeInternalEntity(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:543)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.writeInternalRoot(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:484)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.write(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:447)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.write(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.ReactiveCouchbaseTemplateSupport.lambda$encodeEntity$2(ReactiveCouchbaseTemplateSupport.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.request(FluxUsingWhen.java:319)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:406)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen.subscribe(MonoUsingWhen.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:413)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:431)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:663)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the issue you opened and this is resolved in 5.0.6 - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1736